# FullCalender popover renders on wrong position

Tags: angular, angular-material, calendar, fullcalendar, popover

I am trying to integrate https://fullcalendar.io/docs/angular Plugin into my project, when the events have more than 2-3 items I am opening up the popover, but the position of the popover is wrong. As mention in the official doc, it should open up on top of the date cell

[image]

For me, it is opening like this.

[image]

Below is the snippet of my calendarOptions function:-

```
calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
height: 600,
eventBorderColor: 'white',
dayMaxEvents: true,
moreLinkClick: 'popover',
events: [
  { title: 'event 1', date: '2021-07-20' },
  { title: 'event 2', date: '2021-07-20' },
  { title: 'event 3', date: '2021-07-20' },
  { title: 'event 4', date: '2021-07-20' },
  { title: 'event 5', date: '2021-07-20' },
],};
```

Thanks for the help. Please comment if any additional info is needed.

Comment: Possibly some other CSS is interfering with the fullCalendar CSS. Or perhaps you have modified the fullCalendar CSS itself, and/or used a theme? We need a [mre] really, to be able to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by null offsetParent. Make sure, that your popover div does not contain `position: fixed`.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')
    at t.updateSize (fullcalendar.js:1:163760)
    at t.componentDidMount (fullcalendar.js:1:163043)
    at fullcalendar.js:1:7092
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at fullcalendar.js:1:7072
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at P (fullcalendar.js:1:7031)
    at fullcalendar.js:1:2441
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at D (fullcalendar.js:1:2252)
```